# Ошибка при выкладывании приложения redundant binary upload there already exists

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone, objective-c

Собственно, первый раз выложил приложение (продукт-архив-отправить), он мне на почту прислал 2 замечания:

> Missing recommended icon file - The
>   bundle does not contain an app icon
>   for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly
>   '120x120' pixels, in .png format for
>   iOS versions >= 7.0.
>
> Missing recommended icon file - The
>   bundle does not contain an app icon
>   for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels,
>   in .png format for iOS versions >=
>   7.0.

Первое замечание я исправил, а вот второе не нашёл (кстати, может, подскажете, где оно - не увидел пустого  окошка с разрешением). Ну ладно, исправив одну ошибку, решил попробовать выложить ещё раз - и тут вышла такая ошибка:

[image]

Объясните, пожалуйста, я отправил на одобрение приложение или нет? И, собственно, если я не исправил предупреждения, то это уже придётся делать в версии 1.1 или 2.0?

Я искренне не понимаю какие иконки он от меня ещё требует, посмотрети, вроде все поля заполнены, а сегодня ещё одна ошибка появилась, при чём вчера её небыло
[image]
[image]
[image]

из папки supportingfiles
[image]
из папки apptest
[image]

Comment: @Zatoichy 1 пункт на stackoverflow - нажмите на проблемное изображение, но какое у меня проблемное изображение?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Просмотрите проект в навигаторе(слева) и найдите этот файл. Он возможно будет помечен красным.

Comment: Как вариант, дополнительно, просмотрите Project -> Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: @Zatoichy Project -> Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources по этому пути у меня горит красным файл main.storyboard, а в общем списке красным подсвечивается appTest.xctest, можете что-нибудь подсказать?

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте номер сборки. Target -> General -> Build. Заливка в iTunes Connect ещё не значит отправку на рассмотрение. Зайдите в iTunes Connect и отправьте на рассмотрение самостоятельно, заполнив все нужные поля и ответив на вопросы.

Добавьте иконку для iPad в Assets Catalog.

Comment: @Zatoichy посмотрите, немного дополнил ответ

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Проверьте правильность размеров иконок
![alt text][1]
Покажите ваш Info.plist

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/IWjxr2i.png

Comment: @Zatoichy Спасибо, нак счёт иконок вы были правы, на что за ошибка 90032 "invalid image path cfbundleicons" (второе изображение в моём вопросе)

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов В предыдущем комментарии я просил вас показать Info.plist. Скорее всего ошибка в нём.

Comment: @Zatoichy извините, не заметил про лист, дополнил двумя картинками основной вопрос

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Удалите словари "Icon Files (iOS 5)" и "CFBundleIcons~ipad"

Comment: @Zatoichy  удалил 3 и 4 строки (словари), ошибка осталась

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Попробуйте эти варианты:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522042/invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-cfbundleicons-xcode-5